# How to use CDK to create a proper self-mutating CodePipeline for deploying React application?

Tags: deployment, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, cicd, aws-codepipeline

I've got a monorepo using npm workspaces, consisting of a React app (Vite), Lambdas, a Dynamo table, and some other assets that I'd like to start building pipelines for, using CodePipelines. I'm using latest CDK v2.

The folder structure:

```
my-npm-workspaces-monorepo/
├── node_modules
├── packages/
│   ├── infra
│   ├── lambda
│   └── web/
│       └── react-vite/
│           └── dist
└── package.json
```

So far, without Pipelines, I've got working Stacks for all of these assets and can manually deploy them all successfully w/ the CDK. I've verified that each stack works as intended.

Ultimately, I'd like two pipelines (I think?); front-end and back-end. Right now, I'd just like to see a pipeline work for the react app, standalone.

**The problem;** I've essentially wrapped the working `WebAppStack` I've already built, into a pipeline. It builds and makes its way all the way through the pipeline, until it gets to this point, where one of the 3 FileAsset builds fails with an error. If I retry the failed action, it succeeds all the way through and deploys, and all is good.

[image]

> Error calling startBuild: Cannot have more than 1 builds in queue for
> the account (Service: AWSCodeBuild; Status Code: 400; Error Code:
> AccountLimitExceededException

Here's the CDK goods:

**Launcher.ts**

```js
    import { App } from "aws-cdk-lib";
    import { WebAppPipelineStack } from "./stacks/WebAppPipelineStack";
    
    const app = new App();
    
    new WebAppPipelineStack(app, "WebAppPipelineStack");
    
    app.synth();
```

**WebAppPipelineStack.ts**

```js
    export class WebAppPipelineStack extends cdk.Stack {
        constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
            super(scope, id, props);

            const sourceInput = CodePipelineSource.gitHub("me/my-repo", "main");

            const pipelineBuildInput = new CodeBuildStep("Build", {
                input: sourceInput,
                commands: [
                    "cd packages/web/react-vite",
                    "npm ci",
                    "npm run build"
                ],
                primaryOutputDirectory: "./",
            });

            const pipeline = new CodePipeline(this, "WebAppPipeline", {
                pipelineName: "ServerlessPrototypeWebAppPipeline",
                synth: new ShellStep("Synth", {
                    input: pipelineBuildInput,
                    installCommands: ["npm install -g esbuild ts-node"],
                    commands: [
                        "cd packages/infra",
                        "npm ci",
                        "npx cdk synth"
                    ],
                    primaryOutputDirectory: "packages/infra/cdk.out"
                })
            });

            pipeline.addStage(new WebAppMainPipelineStage(this, "WebAppMainPipelineStage", {
                stageName: "main"
            }));
        }
    }
```

**WebAppMainPipelineStage.ts**

```js
    export class WebAppMainPipelineStage extends Stage {
        constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: StageProps) {
            super(scope, id, props);
    
            new WebAppStack(this, "WebAppStack");
        }
    }
```

**WebAppStack.ts**

```js
    export class WebAppStack extends Stack {
        constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: StackProps) {
            super(scope, id, props);
    
            const deploymentBucket = new Bucket(this, "WebAppWebBucket", {
                bucketName: "my-prototype-web"
            });
    
            const uiLocalDir = "../web/react-vite/dist";
            if (!existsSync(uiLocalDir)) {
                console.warn("Local web app dist folder not found");
                return;
            }
    
            new BucketDeployment(this, "WebAppWebBucketDeployment", {
                destinationBucket: deploymentBucket,
                sources: [Source.asset(uiLocalDir)]
            });
    
            const originIdentity = new OriginAccessIdentity(this, "WebAppWebOriginIdentity");
            deploymentBucket.grantRead(originIdentity);
    
            const distro = new Distribution(this, "WebAppWebDeployDistribution", {
                defaultRootObject: "index.html",
                defaultBehavior: {
                    origin: new S3Origin(deploymentBucket, {
                        originAccessIdentity: originIdentity
                    })
                }
            });
    
            new CfnOutput(this, "WebAppWebDeployOutput", {
                value: distro.distributionDomainName
            });
        }
    }
```

How can I make this work consistently, without having to retry the failed "FileAsset" builds? I feel like I'm almost there, save for this one little hitch.

#### Edit:

I get the exact same result if I combine all commands into the CodePipeline, like so:

```js
        const pipeline = new CodePipeline(this, "WebAppPipeline", {
            pipelineName: "ServerlessPrototypeWebAppPipeline",
            synth: new ShellStep("Synth", {
                input: CodePipelineSource.gitHub("me/my-repo", "main"),
                commands: [
                    //build react
                    "cd packages/web/react-vite",
                    "npm ci",
                    "npm run build",
                    //build cdk
                    "cd ../../../packages/infra",
                    "npm install -g esbuild ts-node",
                    "npm ci",
                    "npx cdk synth"
                ],
                primaryOutputDirectory: "packages/infra/cdk.out"
            })
        });
```

Comment: Could you narrow the scope of the question?  You've asked some architectural questions and a "why is my pipeline not deploying" question.  Consider splitting the question into two.  The good news is your approach is workable.

Comment: @fedonev Yeah, sorry about that - it was intentional. I wanted to shape the question because there's a larger consideration of how I want to do it, for the rest of the stack. The question here is; how do I deploy the React app? I wanted to be sure the best answer is in the context of the larger solution.

Comment: @fedonev Hope that helps. Thanks.

Comment: I'd start by simplifying the pipeline.  Get rid of the `pipelineBuildInput` codebuild step.  Move its react build commands to the `synth` prop's commands.  All 6 commands run in your `ShellStep`.  Set `input: sourceInput`.  This might not fix the problem, but will make dignosis easier.

Comment: @fedonev I tried that earlier today as well, and the result is exactly the same. Every step looks the same in the console. I added an example in the post.

Comment: I'm not shocked that it still fails, but I am surprised that consolidating the steps did not change the number of file assets.  Three things to try:  (1) `cdk deploy` the pipline stack again from your local machine.  I've found that synth step changes aren't always caught by the self-mutation.  Perhaps will help, won't hurt. (2) I thought that `Source.asset` requires the absolute path to your `dist` dir.  I may be wrong.  An absolute path to `dist` might help, won't hurt.  (3) Check the CodeBuild logs for errors.

Comment: @fedonev I destroy --all and deploy --all  between each iteration, just to be entirely sure there's no build weirdness or lingering artifacts. It leaves the web app bucket behind each time, which I also delete manually. `Source.asset` breaks with an absolute path, but works when used as I have it. Nothing in the logs but what I posted, when it fails. I did find this, however: https://repost.aws/questions/QUkKVl--5kSmCW42h1sZyq1w/codebuild-error-cannot-have-more-than-0-builds-in-queue-for-the-account

I mean, I'd love if we could eliminate the extra assets? Is this just normal though?

Comment: @fedonev I suspect it's CDK adding the extra file assets, given what I'm finding out there: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/17744 What about not using a self-mutating pipeline, and just building pipelines for my stacks, that do not include the synth step for CDK? Couldn't I just run cdk commands locally against my environments, and only use pipelines for my app code? This harkens back to my earlier architecture question, but I think it's relevant given the problems I'm having here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255776/discussion-between-fedonev-and-tsar-bomba).

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to add `publishAssetsInParallel: false` to my CodePipeline construct, in order to remove parallel execution. Works every time now! Found [on this thread](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/17744).

```js
        const pipeline = new CodePipeline(this, "WebAppPipeline", {
            pipelineName: "ServerlessPrototypeWebAppPipeline",
            publishAssetsInParallel: false,
            synth: new ShellStep("Synth", {
                input: pipelineBuildInput,
                installCommands: ["npm install -g esbuild ts-node"],
                commands: [
                    "cd packages/infra",
                    "npm ci",
                    "npx cdk synth"
                ],
                primaryOutputDirectory: "packages/infra/cdk.out"
            })
        });
```